# VS 2010 crashes when opening edmx file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have VS 2010 Ultimate and it's crashing when I open an edmx (Entity Framework designer) file.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          2/1/2012 11:53:10 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      blah
Description:
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73
Faulting module name: agcore.dll, version: 4.0.60831.0, time stamp: 0x4e5d716c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000fe4b4
Faulting process id: 0x2f78
Faulting application start time: 0x01cce101ca154d9e
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60831.0\agcore.dll
Report Id: 38221c3f-4cf5-11e1-9b7c-005056c00008
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-02-01T16:53:10.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>86822</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>blah</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>10.0.40219.1</Data>
    <Data>4d5f2a73</Data>
    <Data>agcore.dll</Data>
    <Data>4.0.60831.0</Data>
    <Data>4e5d716c</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>000fe4b4</Data>
    <Data>2f78</Data>
    <Data>01cce101ca154d9e</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60831.0\agcore.dll</Data>
    <Data>38221c3f-4cf5-11e1-9b7c-005056c00008</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Anyone have any ideas as to how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick search on that exception code and fault offset turns up the following links, which have the same solution so it looks promising:

Synopsis:

> Solution was to unregister system.windows.dll from the GAC.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/856122fc-21c2-4fe3-aa89-73653e25afe8

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/234262.aspx/1?Visual+Studio+2010+crashes+when+creating+a+New+Silverlight+Application+in+